# Magento2 get product images externally

Tags: quotes, cart, magento2

I have a external script i use to fetch the current quote products (as external cart for example) This works perfect.

In this code i use the following:

```
$quote = $obj->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuote();
$helper = $obj->get('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
$quote = $helper->getQuote();
$quoteitems = $quote->getAllItems();
$cart= $helper->getCart();  
foreach ($quoteitems as $item)
{
    $_imagehelper = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $img = $_imagehelper->init($product,'category_page_list',array('height' => '100' , 'width'=> '100'))->getUrl();
}
```

This results in: /pub/static/frontend/_view/nl_NL/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/.jpg

While in a layout block i use the following and that works perfect:

```
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
$quote = $helper->getQuote();
$quoteitems = $quote->getAllItems();
$cart= $helper->getCart();  
foreach ($quoteitems as $item)
{
    $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $img = $_imagehelper->init($product,'category_page_list',array('height' => '100' , 'width'=> '100'))->getUrl();
}
```

Im out of ideas.

Comment: Did you find solution for this ?

Answer (score 4):

use the following code

```
// your product's id here 
$pid = 7;
// set image width and height
$imagewidth = 500;
$imageheight = 500;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($pid);
$imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl();
```

Comment: Thanks let me try that!

Comment: @KayIntVeen have you got the exact, what you required ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get product image externally

```
    use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap; 
    include('app/bootstrap.php'); 
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $mediaurl= $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    $state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State'); 
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $pid=1;
    $_product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($pid);
    $data=$_product->getData();
    echo $imageurl=$_product->getImage();
    //print_r($data);
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $mediaurl.'catalog/product'.$imageurl;?>">
```